# Differences/Comparison between the results of scipy.fsolve and scipy.minimize

Tags: python, scipy

I'm a little confused between fsolve and minimize. There are 5 questions I'm looking to try and answer using the below setup, where I have an exact system of equations with 2 solutions.

These are the 5 questions (I restate them at the end of all the code):

1. Why does basinhopping get different answers? If the same initial guesses are used, should you not always get the same output?
2. If one solution has residuals of 7e-15 and the other 2e-22, considering how small these numbers are, are both valid solutions?
3. How to get basinhopping to jump out of local minima? It is quite clear if initial conditions are used for solution 1, basinhopping can sometimes get stuck in solution 2 (question 1). However the reverse is not true, if initial conditions used are solution2, basinhopping can never jump out and find solution1. This is quite concerning considering the global minima is solution1, not solution2. So you would get erronous solutions depending on your initial conditions.
4. Considering fsolve is so heavily dependent on initial guesses (i.e. fsolve easily breaks if initial guesses are even slightly off from the exact solutions). Is minimize the best method always, even for exact systems?
5. Why are the residuals for fsolve and minimization different? I presume I may have set something wrong here, since they should be exactly the same.

Let's say you have a problem

```
solution1=13.4
solution2=600
solution3=7100
solution4=95600

def equations(initial):
    equation1=a*b/(1+b)
    equation2=a*b*c**2/(1+b*c)
    equation3=a*b*d**2/(1+b*d)
    equation4=a*b*c**2*d**2/(1+b*c*d)
```

Now this is an exact system. Therefore fsolve can be used to solve this

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import numpy as np

solution1=13.4
solution2=600
solution3=7100
solution4=95600

def equations(initial):
    a,b,c,d=initial
    equation1=a*b/(1+b)-solution1
    equation2=a*b*c**2/(1+b*c)-solution2
    equation3=a*b*d**2/(1+b*d)-solution3
    equation4=a*b*c**2*d**2/(1+b*c*d)-solution4
    return (equation1,equation2,equation3,equation4)

fsolve(equations(7,30,0.02,500))
```

Now from my understanding, minimize can also be used to solve this same system

```
def equations2(initial):
    a,b,c,d=initial
    equation1=a*b/(1+b)-solution1
    equation2=a*b*c**2/(1+b*c)-solution2
    equation3=a*b*d**2/(1+b*d)-solution3
    equation4=a*b*c**2*d**2/(1+b*c*d)-solution4
    return np.sum(np.array([equation1,equation2,equation3,equation4])**2))
minimize(equations2,x0=(7,30,0.02,500),bounds=((0,np.inf),4)*4) #added bounds to this one
```

From my understanding, these should theoretically gave the same output

```
using_fsolve=fsolve(equations(7,30,0.02,500))
using_minimize=minimize(equations2,x0=(7,30,0.02,500),bounds=((0,np.inf),4)*4)
print(using_fsolve[0],using_minimize.x)
print(sum(using_fsolve[1]['fvec']**2),using_minimize.fun) 
>>> 
[7.23,3.09e1,2.78e-2,4.94e2] [7.2,3.08e1,2.76e-2,5e2]
2.11e-22 8.1e-3
```

It can be observed fsolve found the solution with very small residuals which is great. However, the minimizer actually failed. While it found those values, the status for it was fail. So I tried it again, using Nelder-Mead which I've often had success with.

```
using_fsolve=fsolve(equations(7,30,0.02,500))
using_minimize=minimize(equations2,x0=(7,30,0.02,500),bounds=((0,np.inf),4)*4,method='Nelder-Mead',options={'maxiter':10000}) #had to increase iterations otherwise it would fail
print(using_fsolve[0],using_minimize.x)
print(sum(using_fsolve[1]['fvec']**2),using_minimize.fun) 
>>> 
[7.23,3.09e1,2.78e-2,4.94e2] [7.23,3.09e1,2.78e-2,4.94e2]
2.11e-22 8.86e-12
```

This time it was able to get the exact solution, but for some reason the residual sum is higher in minimize than in fsolve.

Now the whole purpose behind this is because fsolve is highly dependent on the initial guess. I'd like to find the solution to this system of equations independent of what the initial guess is. To that end, I decided to use basinhopping with the previous setup to do this

```
from scipy.optimize import basinhopping
using_fsolve=fsolve(equations(7,30,0.02,500))
using_minimize=basinhopping(equations2,x0=(7,30,0.02,500),minimizer_kwargs={'bounds':((0,np.inf),4)*4,'method':'Nelder-Mead','options':{'maxiter':100000'}})
print(using_fsolve[0],using_minimize.x)
print(sum(using_fsolve[1]['fvec']**2),using_minimize.fun) 
>>> 
[7.23,3.09e1,2.78e-2,4.94e2] [7.23,3.09e1,2.78e-2,4.94e2]
2.11e-22 5.92e-13
```

It was again able to find the exact solution as fsolve, albeit higher residual. Now to test whether this is the true solution, or other solutions exist, I used basin hopping with random inputs

```
using_fsolve=fsolve(equations(7,30,0.02,500))
using_minimize=basinhopping(equations2,x0=(70,300,0.002,5000),minimizer_kwargs={'bounds':((0,np.inf),4)*4,'method':'Nelder-Mead','options':{'maxiter':100000'}})
print(using_fsolve[0],using_minimize.x)
print(sum(using_fsolve[1]['fvec']**2),using_minimize.fun) 
>>> 
[7.23,3.09e1,2.78e-2,4.94e2] [7.23,3.09e1,2.78e-2,4.94e2]
2.11e-22 5.92e-13
#run it again, same inputs
[7.23,3.09e1,2.78e-2,4.94e2] [13.15 128.08 0.30 56.83]
2.11e-22 1.24e-10
#run fsolve this time with the new solution of 13.15, 128.08, 0.3, 56.83
[13.15 128.08 0.30 56.83] [7.23,3.09e1,2.78e-2,4.94e2]
7.40e-15 4.39e-13
#run fsolve and basinhopping using the new solution
[13.15 128.08 0.30 56.83] [13.15 128.08 0.30 56.83]
7.40e-15 1.24e-10
#run again
[13.15 128.08 0.30 56.83] [13.15 128.08 0.30 56.83]
7.40e-15 1.24e-10
```

From here, I have 5 questions:

1. Why does basinhopping get different answers? If the same initial guesses are used, should you not always get the same output?
2. If one solution has residuals of 7e-15 and the other 2e-22, considering how small these numbers are, are both valid solutions?
3. How to get basinhopping to jump out of local minima? It is quite clear if initial conditions are used for solution 1, basinhopping can sometimes get stuck in solution 2 (question 1). However the reverse is not true, if initial conditions used are solution2, basinhopping can never jump out and find solution1. This is quite concerning considering the global minima is solution1, not solution2. So you would get erronous solutions depending on your initial conditions.
4. Considering fsolve is so heavily dependent on initial guesses (i.e. fsolve easily breaks if initial guesses are even slightly off from the exact solutions). Is minimize the best method always, even for exact systems?
5. Why are the residuals for fsolve and minimization different? I presume I may have set something wrong here, since they should be exactly the same.

Putting all the code together for a MVE

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
from scipy.optimize import basinhopping
import numpy as np

solution1=13.4
solution2=600
solution3=7100
solution4=95600

def equations(initial):
    a,b,c,d=initial
    equation1=a*b/(1+b)-solution1
    equation2=a*b*c**2/(1+b*c)-solution2
    equation3=a*b*d**2/(1+b*d)-solution3
    equation4=a*b*c**2*d**2/(1+b*c*d)-solution4
    return (equation1,equation2,equation3,equation4)

def equations2(initial):
    a,b,c,d=initial
    equation1=a*b/(1+b)-solution1
    equation2=a*b*c**2/(1+b*c)-solution2
    equation3=a*b*d**2/(1+b*d)-solution3
    equation4=a*b*c**2*d**2/(1+b*c*d)-solution4
    return np.sum(np.array([equation1,equation2,equation3,equation4])**2))

using_fsolve=fsolve(equations(7,30,0.02,500))
using_minimize=minimize(equations2,x0=(7,30,0.02,500),bounds=((0,np.inf),4)*4,method='Nelder-Mead',options={'maxiter':10000}) 
#using_minimize=basinhopping(equations2,x0=(70,300,0.002,5000),minimizer_kwargs={'bounds':((0,np.inf),4)*4,'method':'Nelder-Mead','options':{'maxiter':100000'}})
print(using_fsolve[0],using_minimize.x)
print(sum(using_fsolve[1]['fvec']**2),using_minimize.fun)
```

Edit:

Just wanted to add an extra bit here, I have tried this exact problem in Mathematica suite using SOLVE. And that gives a range of solutions, and if ignoring all negative solutions, it very nicely provides both of the above solutions I found in python. So is there an option for fsolve to find all viable solutions and display them like in Mathematica (which doesn't take in an input of initial guesses, so I presume it runs a range)?

Comment: there could not be the best & the worst solution - everything depends on "tolerance"(usually it is arg of method)... you should consider the *algorithm* (or solver, or estimator) used in each optimizer_method [investigate manual & tutorials on scipy] - in order to know where the difference comes from, - to choose the one that suits your needs